# Magento and Maximum Server Request Server Setting

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, grouped-products, server-setup, apache

I am running Magento CE 1.9. and the configuration of my Group Product pages requires the page to generate 1,000s of request just for one page. That is not gong to change it is the nature of the type of products we sell.
Our apache.conf the MaxClients: allowed to start is set to 150. 
I have asked my Hosting company to increase that figure to 10,000 and they have refused. What are the best practices in this case?

Comment: Why would it generate 1000 requests? A single page should have a single request, regardless of the number or products. There should be absolutely no need to increase the Max clients setting above 150.